# Multiple instance of a dll in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, tcp, dllimport

I have 10.000 devices and I want to control them by one c++ application. Devices are server and I can control them only by dll. Dll is written for MFC and it wasn't written by me so i cant chance anything on it.

Dll establishs the TCP/IP communication between devices and my application.Every device has different variables. I need to open a new thread for each incoming connection and load an instance of my dll. I couldn't load the different instances of a dll for each thread. everytime it is using the same dll and same data.

How can load multiple instance of a dll ?
Is there any way to do it with c++.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You have 10,000 devices and let me get this straight, you need a new thread for each incoming connection, I assume you understand there is no way to make an incoming connection to all 10,000 devices right?

Comment: @Gizde - You need to post code.

Answer (score 3):

If the data are static it is not possible to have more instance in the same process. You have to modify the dll to have some sort of per context data ( usually class instance would do ). As a general suggestion anyway, **never starts up to 10000 thread on a process**, this will kill the performance. Write a thread pool and let manage the client be served by that pool.

Answer (score 1):

Your situation does not sound hopeful.

Windows will not load more than one instance of a DLL within a given process, ever. If the DLL itself doesn't have the functionality to connect to multiple servers, you would have to create a separate process for each server you need to connect to. In practice, this would be a Bad Idea.

You COULD use LoadLibrary() and UnloadLibrary() to "restart" the DLL multiple times and switch frantically between the different servers that way. Sort of a LoadLibrary()... mess with server... UnloadLibrary()... do it againandagainandagain situation. It would be painful and slow, but might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The only (ugly) way to load a dll multiple times is for every new load you make a copy of the original dll with a unique name in a location that you're in control of.

Load the copy with `LoadLibrary` and setup appropiate function-pointers (`GetProcAddress(...)`) to functions in newly loaded dll for use in your program.

After you're done with it Unload the copy with `FreeLibrary` and remove the copy from disk.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an easy solution to this, as previously covered, you can't create multiple instances of a DLL within an app.

There may be a horrible solution, which is to write a lightweight proxy to listen for inbound requests, and spawn a new instance of the real app on each request, and forward traffic to it - there should be a way to load a new copy of a DLL in each instance (technically you'll be re-opening the same loaded DLL, but it should have separate data spaces).

However, with 10k devices, performance will be horrible. It sounds like the best solution is either to re-implement the protocol (either use a published spec, or reverse-engineer it).